# Getting current page url on wp-admin/admin dashboard?

Tags: php, wordpress, query-variables

Im trying to get the current page url while on the wp-admin/admin dashboard, is it possible?

Im trying to use these codes but i can't seem to get it to work.

```
global $wp;
$current_page = add_query_arg( $wp->query_vars, home_url( $wp->request ) );
```

The output i wanted is like this: `https://example.com/1/wp-admin/admin.php?page=test`
But instead, the output turns like this: `/1/wp-admin/admin.php?page=test&=https://example.com/1`

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If you just want the current URL, you should be able to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which is what `add_query_arg` uses behind the scenes. I think you can also technically say `$url = add_query_arg([]);` to get it, too

Comment: @ChrisHaas i already tried both of those, and this is the output i get: `/1/wp-admin/admin.php?page=test`

The main domain from the url isnt on the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To retrieve the URL of the admin area of your wordpress site, you can use `admin_url()`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/admin_url/

It accepts a path. So you could do `admin_url('admin.php?page=test');` if you like to hard code. But you want to have it dynamically I guess.

I assume, your page is part of the admin menu. Every menu page automatically has a page parameter in the URL like `page=test`.

You want to get the URL of the current page you are looking at, so you can get the page parameter from the URL using `$_GET`.

Putting all this information together, your code can look like:

`$current_page = admin_url( "admin.php?page=".$_GET["page"] );`

Comment: I see, i really have to use t he get request. 
I learn everyday, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 7):

I've found a very handfull solution using [http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function :

```
$current_page = admin_url(sprintf('admin.php?%s', http_build_query($_GET)));
```

`http_build_query()` will automatically transforms all `$_GET` params into a query string which can be append to the base admin URL using `sprintf()`.

However this does not support pages with a different name (eg: `edit.php` instead of `admin.php`). You may use something like this instead, as a helper function, to support every admin pages :

```
/**
 * Get the base URL of the current admin page, with query params.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function get_current_admin_url(): string
{
    return admin_url(sprintf(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));
}

# on your admin page..
$current_page = get_current_admin_url();
```

Beware of the use of this function, URLs can be manipulated by the end user /!\

Comment: there is one issue I found which is if you `echo` the `$current_page` when you are at the wp dashboard (HTTP://site.local/wp-admin/), then it says **http://site.local/wp-admin/wp-admin/**. That means the condition is not working while I am at the dashboard (HTTP://site.local/wp-admin/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the global `$pagenow` or `$typenow` to get the current admin page.

For example, if you want to target only `edit.php?post_type=page`, you can use the following :

```
global $pagenow, $typenow;
  if( ! is_admin() || 'edit.php' !== $pagenow || 'page' !== $typenow ) return;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `add_query_arg()` function that automatically detects current page URL (relative) - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/